# Recurring Billing with Google Wallet

Tags: credit-card, payment-processing, recurring-billing, android-pay

I have a system that is using Google Wallet as payment processor for clients.

Now, the system has a feature that includes monthly subscription and I need to automate the charges for every accounts so the clients will no longer worry on processing their payable each month. Is there any work around with Google Wallet for this?

I have In mind storing Credit Cards in my database but that requires PCI compliance so I guess I'll avoid storing Credit Cards.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, so not sure if you are still waiting for an answer.
Lookup Google Wallet Subscriptions, I believe that should solve your problem